# Redis get TTL and value of a key in one command - nodejs redis

Tags: node.js, redis

Is there option to get the TTL of a key and it's value in one command? Using the redis-cli.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use [TTL](https://redis.io/commands/ttl) command to get remaining time to live of a key that has a timeout and [GET](https://redis.io/commands/get) to get key value. There is no single command to do both. Only way is to use pipeline or transaction

## [ioredis](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ioredis) module

### [pipeline](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ioredis#pipelining) command

```
redis.pipeline().ttl('foo').get('foo').exec(function (err, result) {
  // result === [[null, <ttl>], [null, <value>]]
});
```

### [multi](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ioredis#transaction) command

```
redis.multi().ttl('foo').get('foo').exec(function (err, result) {
  // result === [[null, <ttl>], [null, <value>]]
});
```

## [redis](https://www.npmjs.com/package/redis) module

### [multi](https://www.npmjs.com/package/redis#multiexeccallback) command

```
RedisClient.multi().ttl('foo').get('foo').exec(function (errors, results) {
  // results = [<ttl>, <value>]
});
```

## redis-cli

```
SET foo "bar" EX 42
MULTI
TTL foo
GET foo
EXEC
```

Comment: It doesn't work it tells me: `TypeError: RedisClient.pipeline is not a function`, note that I'm using `RediClient` terminology instead of `redis`